# Keras LSTM Error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, nlp, keras, lstm

I'm loading sentence vectors embeddings (Facebook's InferSent) in my neural network along with other metadata. Here is a glimpse of my dataset:

[My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGrKM.png)

Endpoint Vector: Sentence embedding ndarray. Shape: (4096,1)
Description Vector: Sentence embedding ndarray. Shape: (4096,1)
HTTP Path: Categorical variable (0 or 1)
Is Description: Binary dependent variable (to be predicted)
EndpointDesc Count: Numerical variable (int)
Cosine similarity: Similarity between Endpoint & Description vector.

My dataset consists of 5621 rows and these 6 features. I am new to Neural Networks and wanted to use Endpoint vectors (and later use all the other features) to predict "Is Description" variable. The input shape to the LSTM in Keras is really tricky. I had to do a lot of research on the same, and I'm still not sure whether the data which I feed into the LSTM is in proper shape.

```
X = trainDf.iloc[:, [0]].values
y = trainDf.iloc[:, [3]].values
X = X.reshape(len(X), 1, 1)
y = y.reshape(len(y), 1, 1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X, y))

predict = model.predict(X)
```

The code throws the following error:

```
    Train on 5621 samples, validate on 5621 samples
Epoch 1/1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-c46383616bf3> in <module>()
      8 model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1,1), return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid"))
      9 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 10 model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X, y))
     11 
     12 predict = model.predict(X)

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    963                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    964                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 965                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    966 
    967     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1667                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1668                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1669                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1670 
   1671     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1204                         ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
   1205 
-> 1206                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1207                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1208                         outs = [outs]

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2473         session = get_session()
   2474         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2475                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2476         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2477 

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    952             np_val = subfeed_val.to_numpy_array()
    953           else:
--> 954             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    955 
    956           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

/var/home/pranavmakhijani/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Next steps:
I want to include all the other variables as training features in my dataset.